# Chain Rule Operators AWS Event Bridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I want to set up a rule in Node for AWS Eventbridge that filters for all the name values in detail that have NOT the prefix 'notWantedPrefixSample'. I'm not sure how to code this. Anybody has an idea? thanks in advance!
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html

Here an example if I would filter for that it has the prefix: (so basically I want the oposite)
Would I just use a negation (!) before the brackets?

```
eventPattern: {
      source: ['sourceSample'],
      detail: {
        name:  [{ prefix: 'notWantedPrefixSample' }]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @mafehx. I know this is a very late comment, but were you able to figure out a solution for this by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we solved it using a constellation of different rules.

Comment: Just in case if you're still curious. I got a solution here in my post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971333/aws-eventbridge-rule-pattern-anything-but-with-prefix