# AWS EventBridge Rule pattern "anything-but" with "prefix"

Tags: amazon-web-services, okta, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to setup an AWS EventBridge rule that will filter all Okta user events with rawUserAgent as "anything-but" with the "prefix" **libwww-perl**. My question is that is there a way to chain AWS rule syntax on the same field in the event? I tried something like this, but it didn't work -

```
{
  "detail": {
    "eventType": [{
      "prefix": "user.session.start"
    }],
    "outcome": {
      "result": [{
        "prefix": "FAILURE"
      }]
    },
    "client": {
      "userAgent": {
        "rawUserAgent": [{
          "anything-but": [{"prefix": "libwww-perl"}]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Here's a sample event:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "123",
    "detail-type": "SystemLog",
    "source": "okta",
    "account": "123",
    "time": "2022-06-24T13:07:02Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "uuid": "123",
        "published": "2022-06-24T13:07:02.586Z",
        "eventType": "user.session.start",
        "version": "0",
        "displayMessage": "User login to Okta",
        "severity": "INFO",
        "client": {
            "userAgent": {
                "rawUserAgent": "libwww-perl/6.15",
                "os": "Unknown",
                "browser": "UNKNOWN"
            },
            "zone": "null",
            "device": "Unknown",
            "id": null,
            "ipAddress": "192.168.1.1",
            "geographicalContext": {
                "city": null,
                "state": null,
                "country": "United States",
                "postalCode": null,
                "geolocation": {
                    "lat": 37.751,
                    "lon": -97.822
                }
            },
            "ipChain": [
                {
                    "ip": "192.168.1.1.",
                    "geographicalContext": {
                        "city": null,
                        "state": null
                        "country": "Canada",
                        "postalCode": null,
                        "geolocation": {
                            "lat": 37.751,
                            "lon": -97.822
                        }
                    },
                    "version": "V4",
                    "source": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "device": null,
        "actor": {
            "id": "unknown",
            "type": "User",
            "alternateId": "abc@gmail.com",
            "displayName": "unknown",
            "detailEntry": null
        },
        "outcome": {
            "result": "FAILURE",
            "reason": "VERIFICATION_ERROR"
        },
        "target": null,
        "transaction": {
            "type": "WEB",
            "id": "YrW29nCfOE-MgiNf6-1UkQAAA8I",
            "detail": {}
        },
        "debugContext": {
            "debugData": {
                "loginResult": "VERIFICATION_ERROR",
                "requestId": "abcd",
                "threatSuspected": "true",
                "requestUri": "",
                "url": ""
            }
        },
        "legacyEventType": "core.user_auth.login_failed",
        "authenticationContext": {
            "authenticationProvider": null,
            "credentialProvider": null,
            "credentialType": null,
            "issuer": null,
            "authenticationStep": 0,
            "externalSessionId": "unknown",
            "interface": null
        },
        "securityContext": {
            "asNumber": 11174,
            "asOrg": "qwerty",
            "isp": "qwerty",
            "domain": "qwerty.com",
            "isProxy": false
        },
        "insertionTimestamp": null
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is that is there a way to chain AWS rule syntax on the same field in the event" ?

Comment: Also, can you show an example event?

Comment: Updated the question with a sample event. By chaining I meant is there a way to tell the rule to send only events whose detail.client.userAgent.rawUserAgent is anything but a string starting with the prefix 'libwww-perl'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "eventType": [{
      "prefix": "user.session.start"
    }],
    "client": {
      "userAgent": {
        "rawUserAgent": [{
          "anything-but": {
            "prefix": "libwww-perl"
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    "outcome": {
      "result": [{
        "prefix": "FAILURE"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```